Can a smart contract automatically deduct some amount from one wallet and send to other?
Suppose a company "A" raising investment on blockchain, where the investors are promised X% ROI on their invested amount after N years.
All these investments are sent on a Smart contract (escrow) from where the company A can withdraw that amount.
So, at the end of N years, can this smart contract automatically deduct the promised amount from A's wallet and release it to the investor's wallets, without the need for manual intervention from the investors and Company A?


No, smart contracts can't automate themselves without any external service. You'll need to invoke them to execute any logic.

You can use Chainlink for this. Or run your own servers which will execute once the timer goes.

For deducting the amount from A's wallet - If it's an ERC20 token, then A will have to approve it first, if you're talking about a native token like ETH, A will have to send it.


NO that would simply be SELFDESTRUCT (eip6049)and this opcode is deprecated.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
